# DATETIME SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 Management Studio. I have a `datetime` column in my table.

When I select all contents of the table, the date column has data like `10/10/2013 12:00:00 AM`.

I need a query to display all contents from the table with date column data as `10/10/2013`.

Comment: In your desired output, is that the 10th October or October 10th? (It would be better to give a sample output where the day and month have different values, and you make clear which way around they are)

Comment: If you only ever need the date part - use a `DATE` datatype instead

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: try this link http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Try this one (2008 and higher) -

```
SELECT CAST('10/10/2013 12:00:00 AM' AS DATE)
```

For 2005 -

```
SELECT CAST('10/10/2013 12:00:00 AM' AS VARCHAR(10))
```

Output -

```
10/10/2013
```

Comment: how do use this with the select * from [table] query ??

Comment: I got the following error while executing the above query
Type DATE is not a defined system type.

Comment: @savankuppast this is because DATE datatype is not present in SQL Server 2005 and earlier , was introduced in 2008

Comment: @savankuppast - then you're mistaken in your belief that you're running on SQL Server 2008 (or possibly, you are, but the database is in a lower compatibility mode)

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008, maybe your right about the compatibility mode... but how do i frame the query ?

Comment: this will not ensure the requested format, it will return a date which will be formated by the used tools setup

Comment: @savan kuppast try this query - `SELECT [compatibility_level] FROM sys.databases WHERE name = DB_NAME()`

Comment: @savankuppast Also - `SELECT @@Version`

Comment: @savan kuppast `90 = SQL Server 2005`, `100 = SQL Server 2008`, `110 = SQL Server 2012`

Comment: SELECT @@Version returned me SQL SERVER 2005... asked my boss about this . he told me that the server side is 2005 and client side is 2008.
sorry for my misunderstanding!

Comment: works! but how do i use this with the select * from [table] query

Comment: @savankuppast select <expression> as name, * from [table] Although it is better to list all the columns

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), column, 101) -- u.s standard format mm/dd/yyyy
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), column, 103) -- British/French standard format dd/mm/yyyy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FORMAT()` function:

```
SELECT FORMAT(<your_column>, 'MM/dd/YYYY') FROM <your_table>;
```

Comment: No he can't, `FORMAT` is introduced in SQL Server 2012. Also correct code would be `'MM/dd/yyyy'` - it's case sensitive.

Comment: `FORMAT` is available in SQL Server **2012** only!

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
cast(floor(cast(@dateVariable as float)) as datetime)
```

Comment: That would still include a time component when management studio applies its default formatting. The time component in the example given is already midnight.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function along with styles for DATETIME you can choose the way dates are displayed. 101 would give you `mm/dd/yyyy`, 103 = `dd/mm/yyyy`

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),your_datetime_col, 103) FROM your_table
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/17973)**

Answer (score 0):

For your question i was created one table as

```
 create table dateverify(date_v varchar(20));
```

Inserted single column value

```
   declare @a varchar(20);
      set @a='10/10/2013';
   begin
      insert into dateverify(date_v) values(@a);
   end;
```

using below query,

```
   SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), date_v , 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY] from dateverify;
```

got an answer like you are asked..10/10/2013